# how to create a custom object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a javascript code like this:

```
var myData=[];    
$.getJSON( path_url , function(data){
     var len = data.rows.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
          var code = data.rows[i].codeid;
          var color = data.rows[i].color;
          var obj = {}
          obj[code] = color
          myData.push(obj);
      }
      console.log(myData);
});
```

and the results

```
0: Object{12: "#fc0516"},1: Object{14: "#17a030"},2: Object{31: "#17a030"}
```

but the results I would like this:

```
{12:"#fc0516",14:"#17a030",31:"#17a030"}
```

how can I get the result as above? sorry for my bad english, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `myData` as an object, then use bracket notation to assign the property values

```
var myData = {};
$.getJSON(path_url, function (data) {
    var len = data.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var code = data.rows[i].codeid;
        var color = data.rows[i].color;
        myData[code] = color
    }
    console.log(myData);
});
```

Comment: @insecti4art if you want to thank him for the answer you should mark it as the accepted answer.